# Using Aerospike to process data where uniqueness is defined by combination of keys

Tags: aerospike

I'm trying to understand how to best structure my Aerospike schema. As I'm playing around with it, I'm realizing that part of the problem is me not completely understanding how Aerospike processes data, which seems to be different both from RDBMS and Cassandra.

My dataset is a collection of records such that unique "primary key" is defined by a combination of several fields (I apologize if I'm misusing the term `primary key` in Aerospike sense - originally I was planning to simply concatenate these fields with a delimiter). I need the capability to both retrieve an individual record by specifying all of these fields and retrieve batches that specify a subset. For example, let's say I'm storing demographics data, where my "primary key" is a combination of columns `year`, `location`, and `source` from which I obtained the data. By specifying all 3, I would obtain an exact record, and a collection of records if I specify 2 or just 1.

In RDBMS, I would achieve this using indexes. In Cassandra, the best approach is to add all 3 to the primary key, and rearrange their order in materialized views if I'm not always guaranteed to have partition key available when performing a search.

As I'm playing more with Aerospike, I'm realizing that PKs here are not treated like either of the 2 cases above. Moreover, I'm starting to think that perhaps Aerospike PKs are not meant to be part of user data at all, since they don't get returned by default (unless `sendKeys` is set before write, in which case they're simply duplicated into bins).

It sounds from reading documentation that what I really want may be `secondary indexes` instead (since they allow more flexibility on how the data can be queried)? Are indexes the right approach here or are they discouraged, like in Cassandra? I may be confusing myself by trying to compare Aerospike concepts to other DBs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Great question - needs a detailed answer but let me keep the concepts short at the expense of total accuracy.

1 - Primary Key in Aersopike is string/int/bytes whatever you choose -> is hashed to 20 bytes by client library that your application binds to.  This 20 byte hash is the 'key' sent to the server and used by the server to deal with your record data. So you could create a string key: "2020:san_jose:web" and any data associated with that key will be stored in Aerospike as a record. You could do sendKey or even store your key as another string bin in the record. But what Aerospike uses to track your record is the 20 byte hash of "2020:san_jose:web".  This sort of composite key is not tied implicitly to data bins - rather you explicitly create in your app. This technique can be used to read a batch of records if you can "generate" this string (in your application) for a set of records you are interested in, then use the batch read API. But you cannot use data in bins and tell Aerospike to "generate" this key for you, find matching records and return them.

2 - Can you use secondary indexes?  In Aerospike you can build up to 256 SIs but only use one in a given query call. (I would not recommend building more than a few for RAM plus other operational considerations.) The higher the cardinality of the bin data, the more RAM you would need. The indexes are built in process RAM - that has its own operational implications - and tie query to the hashed keys and therefore the candidate records. So, lets say you use SI on city=="san_jose" - that will yield a subset of records. (Pick an SI that culls the data to 15% of total, ideally - suggestion.)  Now, this will retrieve all records where city bin matches san_jose. This is all in RAM - so that is fast. There after it will read all these records from disk and start shipping back to client.

3 - At this juncture, you have an additional opportunity to write predicate filters of significant complexity. So you can say, of this retrieved set, send me records where year=2020 and source=web ... whatever logical AND OR NOT conditions you need, regexes etc. (I am sacrificing accuracy to drive a larger point. You can also run predex filters on record metadata that happens at the RAM level before record is fetched from disk.)

4 - Finally, why are SIs discouraged in distributed data bases? They work great if the cluster is stable. If nodes are going in or out, data is migrated to create replica copies - SI query runs in parallel to migrating data - you may miss or get duplicates. Think SI query as a relatively 'long' running operation. In Aerospike, if you make sure that data is not migrating before launching an SI query, there is an optional flag you can set - failOnClusterChange - so your query will fail (client gets informed) if a node drops out or joins in during an active SI query. Depending on your data model, you may or may not care about the SI query's 100% accuracy.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, a composite primary key + individual index on each of the 3 fields is probably the way to go (and writing the bins myself instead of relying on sendKeys)? How taxing is this on the RAM? Does it store a duplicate of each indexed field (a string) or just a numeric hash to reference it? This is a side project that relies on AWS, so I am somewhat worried about usage limits skyrocketing the costs.

Comment: If you go the SI model route, you should plan on indexing only one bin. You don't need the rest to be SI'd because you can only use one SI at a time in a query.  You don't need sendKey or store your key in a separate bin. That is unrelated to what you are doing. Composite key is useful if your data model needs a batch read and you can compose an array of keys you want based on your composition pattern in the application, send this array of keys to be batch read. That is the most reliable option.  So SI vs composite key - depends what you are trying to do in your application.

Comment: Predicate Expressions can be used with or without SIs. Since server fetches the record from disk to apply the PredEx before sending data to client, reducing the candidate set of records that the server must fetch by using an SI first helps make it more efficient.

Comment: So what you're saying is that Aerospike can still filter by unindexed field as long as I drive the query from an indexed one? Also, is predicate expression the same as the "where" clause of the query or is it something else?

Answer (score 1):

This code sample may help understand. This would work even if I did not use the Secondary Index on "country", it will just be less efficient - i.e. it will pull every record in that namespace/set and apply the PredEx.

```
public void read () {
                Record record = null;
                Statement stmt = new Statement();
                stmt.setSetName("testset");
                stmt.setNamespace("test");
                stmt.setIndexName("country_idx");
                stmt.setFilter(Filter.equal("country","USA")); 
                stmt.setPredExp(
                        PredExp.stringBin("city"),
                        PredExp.stringValue(".*Diego"),  //prefix-suffix match: prefix.*suffix, ignore case or newline
                        PredExp.stringRegex(RegexFlag.ICASE | RegexFlag.NEWLINE)
                );

                RecordSet recordSet = this.client.query(queryPolicy, stmt);
            while (recordSet.next()) {
                record = recordSet.getRecord();
                System.out.println(record.toString());
            }

         }
```

BTW, the client libraries are open source and have examples of all APIs. For java, see: https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-java/tree/master/examples

Comment: Of course, if you still wanted country to be USA without using SI, you will have to add that condition in the setPredExp() .. you will create one condition for country, second for city, and then an AND condition for the (2) of them.